# Provide default site uuid on install

Tags: 8, configuration

Can I provide default site's uuid static in Drupal 8. I am using docker with Drupal 8 and during configurations import the site is rebuild with docker resulting in different uuid each time. After that I am not able to import configurations.

Thanks

Comment: What does uuid stand for?

Comment: universal unique identifier

Answer (score 0):

You can set the site uuid variable with drush, but a better solution is to use the "config_installer" module.

See https://www.drupal.org/node/2583113 for related discussions.